# What is the difference between fragmentation and true regeneration?

Tags: cell-biology, botany, reproduction

I read in my book that Planaria (flat worms) undergo true regeneration.

Fungi, filamentous algae and protonema of mosses multiply by fragmentation.

What is the exact difference between fragmentation and true regeneration ?

Answer (score 1):

Regeneration is the ability of a creature to repair or regrow an organ after cutting it.
Not all creatures can regenerate.
If you cut a human hand it won't grow to a full human nor the human regrow a new hand
Some salamandras can regrow their tail if amputated but the tail itself won't becoma a salamndra
Planaria, Star fish, and plants can regenerate if the amputated organ has regenerative cells. The original organism will regrow the organ and the organ will grow a full organism.
Fungi, filamentous algae and protonema of mosses do not regenerate when fragmented in the sense that there is no real organ to regenerate. For example, the mycelia of Fungi is composed of many hyphea, creating new is independent of loosing them

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. You seem to address only the definition of regeneration, and not the difference it bears with fragmentation. Further, answers need to be backed up by sources, preferably references to papers from reputable journals, to allow others to background-read on your material.